# Symfony2 "php composer.phar" keeps ending with "Killed"

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I am using composer.phar to install third party bundles in Symfony2. But whenever I run

```
php composer.phar update
```

or with any other composer.phar option, it shows:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

and then "Killed".

I tried to search on this on the web, but didn't really find anything helpful.

Why do you think this is happening?

Comment: It seems that it is a RAM problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667761/composer-killed-while-updating

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried what was suggested in that post. But there's a huge amount of free memory on server. I tried it anyway, and it still didn't work. :( Got any more ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to make your composer update on your dev machine, then upload the composer.lock file on the prod and run the composer install command ?

Comment: I missed the part of uploading .lock file to the server. Thank you pal, that worked :)