# Passing arguments to npm script in package.json

Tags: node.js, parameters, npm, arguments

Is there a way to pass arguments inside of the package.json command?

My script:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "node mytest.js $1 $2 | node_modules/tap-difflet/bin/tap-difflet"
}
```

cli `npm run test 8080 production`

Then on `mytest.js` I'd like to get the arguments with `process.argv`

Comment: In that examples is not passing pipe output.

Comment: there is a simple solution `NUM=1 npm run build` > package.json > "build": "echo $NUM"`

Answer (score 71):

*Note: It only works on shell environment, not on Windows cmd. You should use bash on Windows like Git Bash. Or try Linux subsystem if you're using win10.*

### Passing arguments to script

To pass arguments to [npm script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script), you should provide them after `--` for safety.

In your case, `--` can be omitted. They behaves the same:

```
npm run test -- 8080 production
npm run test 8080 production
```

But when the arguments contain option(s) (e.g. `-p`), `--` is necessary otherwise npm will parse them and treat them as npm's option.

```
npm run test -- 8080 -p
```

### Use positional parameters

The arguments are just appended to the script to be run. Your `$1` `$2` won't be resolved. The command that npm actually runs is:

```
node mytest.js $1 $2 | node_modules/tap-difflet/bin/tap-difflet "8080" "production"
```

In order to make position variable works in npm script, wrap the command inside a shell function:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "run(){ node mytest.js $1 $2 | node_modules/tap-difflet/bin/tap-difflet; }; run"
}
```

Or use the tool [scripty](https://github.com/testdouble/scripty) and put your script in an individual file.

*package.json*:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "scripty"
}
```

*scripts/test*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
node mytest.js $1 $2 | node_modules/tap-difflet/bin/tap-difflet
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on windows machines. I get the error: 'run' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: @BenSouthall Yes, it only works on shell environment, not on Windows cmd. You should use bash on Windows like Git Bash. Or try Linux subsystem if you're using win10.

Comment: I'm using Git Bash, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This throws an error for me: `code ELIFECYCL; npm ERR! Exit status 1` @aleung

Comment: @incodeveritas Please first verify you script. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744964/what-does-the-elifecycle-node-js-error-mean

Comment: https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/478 - getting Error: spawn UNKNOWN on Windows with scripty