# Pass an argument to an npm run script comprising multiple commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'd like to pass an argument into the first of two commands in my npm script:

```
"scripts": {
  "myscript": "a && b"
}
```

When I run `npm run myscript -- --somearg=somevalue`, the argument is passed to command `b` but not command `a`.  Is there some way to instead ensure that the first command receives the argument?

Comment: I think `npm ` appends the additional parameters to the configured value ( `a & b + $@`) and not for every command specified. As a dirty workaround you could specify a shell script `sh <script>.sh` and in the shell script file you could specify `cmd1 -- $@ && cmd2 -- $@` which will execute multiple commands.

Comment: See answer under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221098/passing-arguments-to-npm-script-in-package-json

Comment: Or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json/51401577#answer-51401577) for a solution which runs cross-platform (i.e. Bash, Windows Command Prompt / cmd.exe, and PowerShell etc..).

Comment: Perhaps what you need is the `pre` and `post` hooks for scripts?
The docs describe that if you add a script prefixed with `pre` or `post`, like `postmyscript`, it will run after your script. However, your script is the one that gets the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
"scripts": {
  "myscript": "a",
  "postmyscript": "b"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution after searching a lot from this discussion:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9627#issuecomment-152607809

and

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9627#issuecomment-178576802

**Solution 1.**
So in your package json add a config object like so

```
{
  "name": "packageName",
  "config" : { "variable1" : "value1" }
}
```

then you can access the variable like so **on windows**

```
    {
      "name": "packageName",
      "config" : { "variable1" : "value1" },
      "scripts": {
              "myscript": "a -c %npm_package_config_variable1%  && b -c %npm_package_config_variable1%"
      }
    }
```

**in mac/linux I am assuming (not a 100%)**

```
{
  "name": "packageName",
  "config" : { "variable1" : "value1" },
  "scripts": {
          "myscript": "a -c $npm_package_config_variable1  && b -c $npm_package_config_variable1"
  }
}
```

then you can override the variable by calling the script like so:

```
npm run myscript --packageName:variable1=value2
```

**Solution 2.**

no need for the config entry in the package.json

```
{
  "name": "packageName",
  "scripts": {
          "myscript": "a -c %npm_config_variable1%  && b -c %npm_config_variable1%"
  }
}
```

and call it like so

```
npm run myscript --variable1=value2
```

**reason to pick one over the other:**

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9627#issuecomment-178813965

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple solution when working with [Yarn v2 "berry"](https://dev.to/arcanis/introducing-yarn-2-4eh1):

```
"scripts": {
  "myscript": "a $@ && b $@"
}
```

Since yarn berry hosts it's own little cross-platform bash-like environment for executing the `scripts` in a package, this may work cross platform as well.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative way, this is work with npm less additional setting.

But required bash(or zsh and so on).

```
"scripts": {
  "myscript": "bash -c 'a $@ && b $@' bash"
}
```

(last word 'bash' is needed(but no used), because of first arg set to $0, not included $@)

Answer (score -2):

```
npm run myscript -- --foo=1 --bar=2
```

See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script