# Pass command line args to npm scripts in package.json

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I have the below scripts in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "vumper": "node node_modules/vumper/index.js",
    "format": "prettier --single-quote -width=80 --write package.json"
 },
```

The 'vumper' package takes in a command line argument (such as 'dv'). What I would like to be able to do is have a command that runs both of these in succession.

Essentially, I would like to be able to run:

```
npm run vumber dv
```

and then

```
npm run format
```

but in one command, something like

```
npm run my-build dv
```

which would run both of the above commands, correctly accepting the command line argument 'dv' and passing it to the first npm run vumper. Is this possible?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

#### Short Answer:

Essentially, what you're wanting is to have an npm-script something like this, whereby `<arg-here>` is provide via the CLI;

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "my-build": "npm run vumper <arg-here> && npm run format",
  ...
},
...
```

However, unfortunately npm does not have a built-in feature to achieve this.

The special npm option `--`, (refer to the end of *Solution 1* below for further info about this option), can only be used to pass an argument to the *END* of a script but NOT into the MIDDLE. So, if your two commands were in the opposite order, the `--` option could be used like this:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "my-build": "npm run format && npm run vumper --",
  ...
},
...
```

To overcome the limitation of there being no built-in feature to pass an argument into the MIDDLE of a script consider the following solutions:

1. For a Bash only solution refer to the *"Solution 1"* section.
2. If cross platform support is required then follow the solution described in the *"Solution 2"* section.

---

### Solution 1 - *Bash (MacOS/Linux/ etc..)*:

Configure your `my-build` script in the `scripts` section of *package.json* to invoke a Bash [shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions), as shown below:

**package.json**

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "my-build": "func() { npm run vumper \"$1\" && npm run format; }; func",
  "vumper": "node node_modules/vumper/index.js",
  "format": "prettier --single-quote -width=80 --write package.json"
},
...
```

**Explanation:**

The Bash function named `func` does the following:

1. Firstly runs `npm run vumper <arg>`. Whereby `<arg>` will be the shell argument passed via the CLI. It is referenced in the script using `$1` (i.e. the first [positional parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html)/argument).
2. Subsequently it runs the script named `format` via the command `npm run format`.

These two `npm run`  commands are chained using the `&&` operator, so the second `npm run format` command will only run if the initial `npm run vumper <arg>` command completes successfully (i.e. returns a `0` exit code).

**Running `my-build` script:**

To invoke `my-build` via your CLI you'll need to run:

```
npm run my-build -- dv
```

Note:

1. In this instance the trailing `dv` part is the argument that will be passed to your `vumper` script.
2. The special option `--` must be specified before the argument. The [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) describe the `--` option as:

   > ... The special option `--` is used by [`getopt`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147143/when-and-how-was-the-double-dash-introduced-as-an-end-of-options-delimiter) to delimit the end of the options. npm will pass all the arguments after the `--` directly to your script: ... The arguments will only be passed to the script specified after `npm run` and not to any pre or post script.

---

### Solution 2 - *Cross-platform*:

For a cross-platform solution, (one which works successfully with Bash, Windows Command Prompt / cmd.exe, and PowerShell etc..), you'll need to utilize a nodejs helper script as follows.

**run.js**

Let's name the nodejs script *run.js* and save it in the projects root directory, at the same level as *package.json*.

```js
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

const arg = process.argv[2] || 'dv'; // Default value `dv` if no args provided via CLI.

execSync('npm run vumper ' + arg, {stdio:[0, 1, 2]});
execSync('npm run format', {stdio:[0, 1, 2]});
```

**package.json**

Configure your `my-build` script to invoke *run.js* as follows:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "my-build": "node run",
  "vumper": "node node_modules/vumper/index.js",
  "format": "prettier --single-quote -width=80 --write package.json"
},
...
```

**Running `my-build` script:**

As per *Solution 1*, to invoke `my-build` via your CLI you'll need to run:

```
npm run my-build -- dv
```

**Explanation:**

- *run.js* utilizes [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) to obtain the argument passed via the CLI (e.g. `dv`). If no argument is provided when running `npm run my-build` the default value, (i.e. `dv`), is passed to the `vumper` npm-script.
- *run.js*  also utilizes [`child_process.execSync(...)`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) to *shell-out*/invoke the two `npm run` commands.

Comment: Isn't there a cli npm package that would simply do something like
`const args = process.argv.slice(3);`
`const command = args.reduce(`
``(res, arg, index) => res.replace(new RegExp(`\\$${ index + 1 }`, 'g'), arg),``
`process.argv[2]`
`);`
`const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;`
`execSync(command, { stdio: [0, 1, 2] });`
?.
This way I can just wrap any script with \" and prefix it with such cli and run any script with ordered arguments...

Answer (score 36):

Npm now *has* **a built-in option to pass cli arguments directly to scripts**.
The cli arguments are stored in environmenet variables with prefix `npm_config_<flagname>`, and they required a very strict syntax, with the form `--<flagname>=<flagvalue>`.

Example:

```
 "my-build": "npm run vumper %npm_config_myflag% && npm run format",
```

In the terminal, run `npm run my-build --myflag=my_value` to execute `npm run vumper my_value && npm run format`.

Note:

To refer the environment variable in the npm script, you have to use the platform specific syntax, ie `%npm_config_myflag%` in Windows or `$npm_config_myflag` in Linux.

UPDATE:

To avoid **risks of conflict** with the npm_config variables used to configure npm itself, just **prefix your arguments with a unique prefix**, such as the name of your app.

The potential conflict is a very common problem, which applies in many contexts: any application could use environment variables already used by other applications; for this reason, the environment variables are usually prefixed with the name of the application (eg NVM_HOME, JAVA_HOME). But this potential conflict is not a good reason to avoid using environment variables. The same in my opinion applies to npm params / npm_config env vars. [The doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#environment-variables) does not say anything about the risk of conflicts, implying I guess they should be managed as usual.

Comment: Platform specific was key for me. I was trying  `$npm_config_myflag` on Windows and losing my mind

Comment: npm creates its own env vars named `npm_config_*` for internal purposes too. Be sure to choose a name for the flag/option (e.g. `--myflag=*`) that does not override an internally used one, as this has potential to produce unwanted results. You can `cd` to your project dir and run `npm run env` to list the env vars that npm adds. E.g. passing `--tag=foo` is not a good idea because npm adds the `npm_config_tag` env var (it's value is typically set to `latest`). By using this method It's uncertain which internal `npm_config_*` vars npm may add in the future which you may eventually be overriding.

Comment: You can refer to this approach, but using this approach might be dangerous as explained by @RobC in the comment. So not with respect to this questions solution but in general if someones requirement is to append the argument in the end of the command then do not use the environment variable approach in such case he/she can use npm run <scriptname> -- <argument>.

Answer (score 7):

My preferred method is by using environment variables:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "ncc-build": "ncc build $ACTION/src/index.ts -o $ACTION/dist",
    "build:pr-changelog": "ACTION=pr-changelog npm run ncc-build",
  }
}
```

It should work in UNIX systems. I'm not sure about windows platfrom compatibility  though.

Comment: yes, it's not working in windows platform

Comment: for Windows you would do `set ACTION=...`, but if you want to use in any platform, use the package [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

Answer (score 3):

a different approach for doing this - to reach super deep into you dependency chain:

**npm scripts section:**

```
"test:local": "cross-env-shell UPDATE_BASELINE=false UPDATE_MODULE=%npm_config_vizdifsingle% run-p koa:ci wdio:local",
"test:remote": "cross-env-shell UPDATE_BASELINE=false  UPDATE_MODULE=%npm_config_vizdifsingle% run-p localtunnel:start koa:ci wdio:remote"
```

by using crossenv and npm's value placement you can pass args to env.args

like this:

```
npm run test:local --vizdifsingle=some,value,or,values
```

it will be available to you in

```
process.env.npm_config_update_module
```