# Passing arguments to combined npm script

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, webpack, gulp

I have in my package.json the following

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "prod": "gulp build --production && webpack --env.config=production"
}
```

I now want to pass a parameter "theme" to both gulp and webpack to be able to adjust the output of the build process from the command line.

I figured out how to pass it to webpack: `npm run prod -- --env.theme=themename` but gulp does not take care of this. I also played around with the `yargs`-package, `processs.argv` and bash string substitution by changing the npm script to `"gulp build --production \"$1\" && webpack --env.config=production"` but that did not work out either.

How can this be achieved? What am I missing? Any hints highly appreciated!

Comment: It's not completely clear what you want to achieve. Are you trying to pass the argument (i.e. `--env.theme=themename`) to both the _gulp_ and _webpack_ command in your `prod` script via the command line? You mention _"...but gulp does not take care of this"_ - what do you mean by that?. If your npm script was just  `"prod": "gulp build --production"` and you invoke it via your CLI like this: `npm run prod -- --env.theme=themename` does _gulp_ do what you want it to do?

Comment: @RobC Thanks for reaching out. Basically I want to pass information from the command line to `npm run prod` in a way, that it can be processed in my gulpfile.js and in my webpack.config.js, so that I'm able to adjust the building process accordingly. And to your specific question: If I adjust the npm script and the CLI call accordingly, the information is available in the gulpfile.js, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Bash you can use a [function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions) in your npm-script.

For instance:

```json
"scripts": {
    ...
    "prod": "func() { gulp build --production \"$1\" && webpack --env.config=production \"$1\"; }; func"
}
```

However, for a cross-platform solution you'll need to consider invoking a nodejs script which exec's the commands - in a similar way shown in *Solution 2* of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json#answer-51401577).