# Cross-platform way to pass environment variables as arguments to npm scripts

Tags: npm, cross-platform, npm-scripts

From both Windows or Linux, I want a way to pass args to a `npm script`, but have them be injected as environment variables

From the command line, I'd start my project in this fashion:

```
npm run start -- --env=dev --host=localhost --port=1234
```

To consume my cli args & inject them as env variables regardless of platform, I used the [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env#usage) npm package :

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env env=%env% host=%host% port=%port% my-app"
  },
```

I understand the above is invalid syntax, but can that `start` script somehow consume the args I pass instead of forwarding them on to `my-app`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately npm does not, nor intends to, provide a builtin feature which allows arguments to be passed to the middle of a npm script *(as stated [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/5518#issuecomment-46915480))*. Arguments can only be passed to the end of a script.

For Linux and macOS you can utilize [bash functions](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) in npm-scripts to pass arguments to the middle of a script, as per my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51590079/passing-arguments-to-combined-npm-script/51595953#51595953). However Windows will choke at such a solution.

As cross-platform compatibility is a requirement, consider moving the logic currently in your `start` script into a separate nodejs utility script. The nodejs script can then be invoked via the npm-script named `start`.

The following describes how to achieve your requirement in a cross-platform compatible way.

---

#### 1. Custom nodejs utility script.

Create a nodejs script as follows. Let's name the script *start.js* and save it in the root of your project directory, i.e. at the same level where your *package.json* file currently resides.

```js
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

const args = process.argv.splice(2, process.argv.length - 2)
    .map(arg => arg.replace(/^--/, ''));

execSync(`cross-env ${args.join(' ')} my-app`, {stdio:[0, 1, 2]});
```

**Explanation:**

1. In the first line we `require` nodes builtin [`execSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options). We'll utilize this to run `cross-env` and set the environment variables.
2. Nodes builtin [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) obtains the arguments passed via the command-line. The first two items in nodes `process.argv` are:

   - The path to the executable running the JavaScript file.
   - The path of the JavaScript file being executed.
3. However, we're only interested in the elements from the third item in the array onwards - as these will be your arguments passed via the CLI. These lines which read;

   ```js
   const args = process.argv.splice(2, process.argv.length - 2)
       .map(arg => arg.replace(/^--/, ''));
   ```

   create an `args` variable and assigns an Array containing each argument passed via the CLI. The first two aforementioned items in point 2 are omitted from the array using the [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method. In the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method we remove the `--` prefix from each argument.
4. The last line reading:

   ```
   execSync(`cross-env ${args.join(' ')} my-app`, {stdio:[0, 1, 2]});
   ```

   invokes `cross-env` and places the arguments as a string using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and the Array [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method. The [`stdio`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_stdio) part configures the pipes for `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` in the child process.

**Note:** If your targeting older versions of node that don't support *Template Literals* then you can substitute this line with the following instead. This handles string concatenation using the `+` operator:

```
execSync('cross-env ' + args.join(' ') + ' my-app', {stdio:[0, 1, 2]});
```

Similarly, if ES6 arrow functions aren't supported change the `map()` to use standard functions. For instance:

```
.map(function(arg) {
  return arg.replace(/^--/, '');
});
```

---

#### 2. package.json script.

Redefine your `start` script in *package.json* as follows:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "node start"
},
```

Here we are asking node to invoke the *start.js* script.

**Note** If you prefer to save the *start.js* file in a directory location which is different to the aforementioned root of your project directory, then you'll need to define the path to *start.js* as necessary. The path should be relative to *package.json*. For instance:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./the/path/to/start"
},
```

---

#### 3. Running the npm-script.

The npm `start` script can be invoked via your CLI by running:

```
$ npm start -- --env=dev --host=localhost --port=1234
```

The `run` part, i.e. `npm run start ...` is not required when invoking the npm's `start` script.