# Pass an environment variable to a npm script that invokes a node script?

Tags: npm, webpack, environment-variables, package.json, npm-scripts

I have the following node script to start a react app. It sets a variamle in the .env. Is there a way to set this script in the package.json, so it can take a parameter from the terminal?

script in the terminal that sets a color in the .env:

```
set COLOR=blue&& node scripts/start.js
```

package.json, how to hand over the color parameter?

```
"scripts": {
  "startWithColor": "set COLOR=$COLOR&& node scripts/start.js",
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-platform way to pass environment variables as arguments to npm scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656882/cross-platform-way-to-pass-environment-variables-as-arguments-to-npm-scripts)

Comment: Given my answer at the link in the comment above. You need to make the following changes to work for your scenario: **1)** Change the last line of the node.js utility script to `execSync(\`cross-env ${args.join(' ')} node scripts/start.js\`, {stdio:[0, 1, 2]});`  **2)** Install [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env), i.e. run `npm i -D cross-env` in your project directory. **3)** Change your npm-script in _package.json_ to `"startWithColor": "node start",`  (note: this points to the node.js utility script). **4)** To invoke your script run `npm run startWithColor -- --COLOR=blue`