# How to pass arguments to an npm script which executes other scripts and commands sequentially

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I have a javascript file, **do-stuff.js**, which does stuff with the arguments received from command line

```
// do-stuff.js
doSomething(process.argv[2]);
doSomethingElse(process.argv[3]);
```

I can execute **do-stuff** with an npm script like this

```
"scripts": {
  "do-stuff": "node do-stuff"
}
```

I call the script from command line and everything works fine

```
npm run do-stuff -- --firstArg=abc --secondArg=123
```

Now I create a second file, **do-more-stuff.js** which I want to execute sequentially, after having executed **do-stuff.js**.

So I create a second script

```
"scripts": {
   "do-stuff": "node do-stuff",
   "do-more-stuff": "npm run do-stuff && npm run do-more-stuff",
}
```

But now, if I call **do-more-stuff** with the same arguments as before

```
npm run do-more-stuff -- --firstArg=abc --secondArg=123
```

I see that the parameters are not passed to **do-stuff**.

Is there a way to make an npm script which executes commands sequentially to be able to receive arguments from command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass command line args to npm scripts in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json)

Comment: The issue is that npm does not, nor intends to, provide a builtin feature which allows arguments to be passed to the middle of a npm script - as stated [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/5518#issuecomment-46915480). However my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json#answer-51401577) to the possible duplicate question provides a solution(s) to overcome this limitation.

Comment: Using `node_config_*` variables might work in this case https://stackoverflow.com/a/60458728/728287