# Get version level from npm script

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to write [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) which run when bumping the package version via [`npm version`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version). I do not intend for my scripts to be invoked directly via `npm run _____`; instead, they should be invoked by npm, when `npm version ____` (or `preversion` or `postversion`, etc) is called.

How can I refer to the version level argument in my scripts?

e.g. If my script runs as `preversion` and was invoked from `npm version major`, how can my script refer to `major`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass command line args to npm scripts in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json)

Comment: Sorry, can you please explain how I can use the solution to that question to answer mine? I am not writing an arbitrary script which is invoked directly by `npm run myScript`; instead `myScript` is invoked on the `version` lifecycle hook. The `npm version` command already takes an argument and does its own validation on that. I simply want to refer to the value of that arg within `myScript`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within my script, I can refer to `process.env.npm_config_argv`. Its value is a JSON string which contains the original args to npm.

If my package.json contains:

```
"scripts": {
  "preversion": "node log_argv"
}
```

And `log_argv.js` contains:

```js
console.log('Type:', typeof process.env.npm_config_argv);
console.log('Value:', process.env.npm_config_argv);
console.log('Original npm args:', JSON.parse(process.env.npm_config_argv).original);

throw new Error("aborting");
```

And I run `npm version patch`, then I see the output:

```
Type: string
Value: {"remain":["patch"],"cooked":["version","patch"],"original":["version","patch"]}
Original npm args: [ 'version', 'patch' ]
```

Comment: `process.env.npm_config_argv` is `undefined` for me :((