# Pass arguments to a multi-command script of npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Here is my `scripts` object:

```
"scripts": {
    "version-update": "node version-generator.js",
    "build": "npm run version-update && webpack --mode production"
}
```

I want to pass some arguments to my `version-update` command on `build` command calling, like this:

```
npm run build -- --type=1
```

and fetch `--type` arg in my `version-generator.js`.

But when I did this, `-- --type=1` only effects `webpack --mode production` and I can not achieve it in `version-generator.js`.

Comment: The easiest way is using env var

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass command line args to npm scripts in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a not-so-pretty looking workaround that works only on linux.

```
  "scripts": {
    "version-update": "node version-generator.js",
    "build": "call_with_args() { npm run version-update -- \"$@\"; webpack --mode production \"$@\"; } && call_with_args"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks you, but I'm a windows user!

Answer (score -1):

When you run `npm run build -- --type=1` it's passed `type=1` as argument to the script command `build` .

Based on the npm command syntax `npm run <command> [-- <args>]`, What you want is similar to this:

```
"build": "npm run version-update -- <arg> && webpack --mode production"
```

Unfortunately npm does not have a built-in feature to achieve this. Note the `--` is needed to separate the params passed to npm command itself and params passed to your script. And the arguments are passed to the END of a script but NOT into the MIDDLE. So, you could try the following:

```
"build": "webpack --mode production && npm run version-update --"
```

Comment: Thank you, I need to exec version-update before webpack

Comment: [_"unfortunately npm does not have a built-in feature to achieve this"_ and _"to the END of a script but NOT into the MIDDLE"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json#answer-51401577) - The _"Short Answer"_ section of my answer wasn't actually the solution.