# NPM custom arguments produces Powershell error

Tags: powershell, npm

I am trying to launch a npm script with a custom argument:

```
"publish-local": "ng build $PROJECT && cd dist/$PROJECT && npm publish --registry=http://my.local.npm.registry"
```

This is how I am trying to call it from the prompt:

```
PROJECT=my-lib npm run publish-local
```

This is how I have seen it should work on different web sources (for example:[here](https://medium.com/@kevinkreuzer/flexible-npm-scripts-89b5ec0c5b46))

Anyway, trying to do that, I get this error:

```
PROJECT=my-lib: The term 'PROJECT=my-lib' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:1 char:1
```

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** The example(s) that you've seen that *"should work"* will only work on [**nix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like). They *do not* work via PowerShell, nor via Command Prompt on Windows.

Given that you're wanting to pass an argument to a npm-script, whereby that argument is consumed two times in the middle of that script I suggest you consider the following approach instead:

The following suggested approach is very similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json/51401577#51401577).

---

### Solution - Cross-platform:

For a cross-platform solution, (one which works successfully with **nix*, Windows Command Prompt and PowerShell etc..), you'll need to utilize a nodejs helper script.

Let's name the nodejs script *publish-local.js* and save it in the projects root directory, at the same level as *package.json*.

**publish-local.js**

```js
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

const arg = process.argv[2] || 'my-lib'; // Default value `my-lib` if no args provided via CLI.

execSync('ng build ' + arg + ' && cd dist/' + arg +
    ' && npm publish --registry=http://my.local.npm.registry', {stdio:[0, 1, 2]});
```

**package.json**

Configure your `publish-local` script to invoke *publish-local.js* as follows:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "publish-local": "node publish-local",
},
...
```

**Running publish-local script:**

To invoke `publish-local` via your CLI you'll need to run:

```
npm run publish-local -- my-lib
```

---

**Notes:**

- Inside *publish-local.js* take note of the line that reads:

  ```js
  const arg = process.argv[2] || 'my-lib'; // Default value `my-lib` if no args provided via CLI.
  ```

  It specifies a default value to use when no argument is provide via the CLI.

  So, If you were to currently run the npm script without passing an argument:

  ```
  npm run publish-local
  ```

  or run it with passing an argument:

  ```
  npm run publish-local -- my-lib
  ```

  They are essentially the same. However if you were to provide an argument that is different to `my-lib`, i.e. one that is different to the default specified in *publish-local.js*, it will take precedence. For example:

  ```
  npm run publish-local -- some-other-lib
  ```
- For a further understanding of this solution I suggest you read my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json/51401577#51401577) that I previously linked to.
- The default shell used by npm is `cmd.exe` on Windows, and `sh` on **nix* - this given solution will work successfully with either.
- If you only intend to use/support more recent versions of node.js that support [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) features, such as [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) then you could refactor *publish-local.js* as follows:

  **publish-local.js** (refactored using ES6 features)

  ```js
  const { execSync: shell } = require('child_process');

  const [ , , projectName='my-lib' ] = process.argv;

  shell(`ng build ${projectName} && cd dist/${projectName} && npm publish --registry=http://my.local.npm.registry`, {stdio:[0, 1, 2]});
  ```