# Passing arguments to combined npm script with condition

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, parceljs

I got ParcelJS project with multiple `package.json` file scripts commands.

```
"scripts": {
    "parcel": "./node_modules/@mms/parcel-bundler/bin/cli.js",

    "start": "parcel templates/layouts/index.pug",
    "start:news": "parcel templates/layouts/news.pug",
    "start:news-inner": "parcel templates/layouts/news-inner.pug",

    more and more commads here...
}
```

The `package.json` *file above works fine* but it's become bigger and unreadable as the project is growing up.

So I want to compress `package.json` scripts block by remove all `:postfix` pages names and pass the necessary page name as NPM arguments with alternative fallback page name at, if there is no page specified

Sample of *expected* code:

```
"scripts": {
    "parcel": "./node_modules/@mms/parcel-bundler/bin/cli.js",
    "start": "parcel templates/layouts/\"$1 || index\".pug"
}
```

Of course the example above isn't working because it has syntax problems, so as the first steps I tried the simpler code below, and it's not working too, and I don't know why.

```
"scripts": {
    "parcel": "./node_modules/@mms/parcel-bundler/bin/cli.js",
    "start": "parcel templates/layouts/\"$1\".pug"
}
```

Terminal result of the above script runing:

```sh
$ yarn start index
yarn run v1.19.1
$ parcel templates/layouts/"${1}".pug index
Server running at http://localhost:1234 
  No entries found.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Could you please help me to fix this NPM script?

Comment: In the link provided I explain that on a _*nix_ platform you can utilize a shell function in npm scripts because npm utilizes `sh` to run scripts. Given your scenario you can set your `start` script to `"start": "func () { parcel templates/layouts/\"${1:-index}\".pug; }; func"`. When running `npm start` (i.e. without passing an arg) it will set path to `templates/layouts/index.pug`, i.e. it uses the default `index`. When you run `npm start -- news` (i.e. pass a `news` arg) it sets the path to `templates/layouts/news.pug`. For a x-platform solution see section _"Solution 2 - Cross-platform"_

Comment: Hi, while I delve into the proposed answer =)

Comment: Hi, If you're wondering what the `${1:-index}` part is in my previous comment, refer to the  `${parameter:-word}` example in [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). It provides us with a mechanism to specify a default value (`index`) which can be substituted by an arg provided via the CLI - such as; `news`, `news-inner`, etc. As mentioned previously, for a cross-platform solution you'll need to utilize a _node.js_ helper script instead - On windows npm utilizes `cmd` as the default shell, and _not_ `sh`.

Comment: I choose the second mentioned method, and it's work

Comment: I close this ASK, but wonna some roll my comments in you mentioned answer by the link below (see you there!): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json