# Pass values from cmd to npm script

Tags: powershell, npm, cmd, npm-scripts

I've searched for days but did not find an answer that worked for my problem.

I want to run a npm script through cmd or Powershell in **Windows** and pass values for script variables.
I would like the bellow script in `package.json`:

```js
"scripts": {
    "happy-birthday": "echo Happy birthday $NAME and many returns!"
    }
```

To output:

*Happy birthday Danny and many returns!*

With a command like:

```
npm run happy-birthday --NAME=Danny
```

Everything I tested so far gives me:

*Happy birthday $NAME and many returns!*

It feels like npm does not recognize this as a variable and prints it like it is a string. I also tested %NAME%.

Npm version - 6.12.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass arguments to the middle of npm scripts, argument(s) can only be passed to the end of them. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json/51401577#51401577) for further explanation.

Given your example, consider the following solution which will work successfully across all platforms:

1. In your *package.json* file define your `happy-birthday` npm script as follows:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "happy-birthday": "node -e \"console.log('Happy birthday %s and many returns!', process.argv[1] || 'Jane')\""
   }
   ```
2. Then run the following command via *cmd* or *Powershell* (or any other command line tool).

   ```
   npm run happy-birthday -- Danny
   ```

   This will print:

   > Happy birthday Danny and many returns!

   **Note:** If you just run the following command, i.e. without passing an argument:

   ```
   npm run happy-birthday
   ```

   It will print the default name instead:

   > Happy birthday Jane and many returns!

---

**Explanation:**

- The npm script utilizes the nodejs command line option [`-e`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_e_eval_script) to evaluate the inline JavaScript as follows:

  ```js
  console.log('Happy birthday %s and many returns!', process.argv[1] || 'Jane')
  ```
- The arguments passed via the CLI, e.g. `Danny`, are read using [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) - whereby we reference the Array element at index 1.
- The [Logical OR Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), i,e. `||` is utilized to return `Jane` when no argument is passed.

---

#### Edit: Setting environment variables instead

Alternatively may want to consider setting an environment variable and referencing it in your npm script.

1. In your npm script define your `happy-birthday` npm script as follows:

   ```
   "happy-birthday": "echo Happy birthday %NAME% and many returns!"
   ```

   <sub>**Note** the `%NAME%` notation used by Windows only to reference the variable.</sub>
2. **Using cmd**

   When using cmd (i.e. *Command Prompt*) you'll need to run the following command:

   ```
   set NAME=Danny&& npm run happy-birthday
   ```

   **Using Powershell**

   When using *Powershell* you'll need to run the following command instead:

   ```
   $env:NAME="Danny" ; npm run happy-birthday
   ```

**Note:** The default shell that npm utilizes for npm scripts is `sh` on **nix* and `cmd` on windows. Therefore the aforementioned methods defined in steps 1 and 2 will fail on **nix* platforms.

If cross-platform support is requirement and you do want to take this approach of setting environment variables and referencing them via npm scripts, then consider utilizing the [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) package.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer! It worked! Could you please also provide an example with passing more arguments than just one?

Comment: For more than one argument  you'll need to set your npm script to something like this: `"foo": "node -e \"console.log('First: %s Second: %s Third: %s', process.argv[1], process.argv[2], process.argv[3])\""`. Then if you run: `npm run foo -- A B C` it will print: `First: A Second: B Third: C`. I've also updated the answer to show you you can set environment variables and reference them.