# pass variable to npm command string (not the script run by npm command)

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, npm-scripts

Is it possible to pass an argument to the npm command string? The info might be somewhere in docs, but brief digging didn't get me any results, moreover, it is probably beneficial to the large audience.

For example, i have a command `build:docker` in `package.json`:

```
   "scripts": {
      "build:docker": "tsc -b && sh dist.sh && docker build -t repo_name/image .",
   },
```

I want to pass the `tag` variable to the command string, ex:

```
"build:docker": "tsc -b && sh dist.sh && docker build -t repo_name/image:$tag ."
```

and run it as `npm run build:docker --tag '1.0'`.

Is something like this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Use a shell function. For example redefine your npm script as: `"build:docker": "func() { tsc -b && sh dist.sh && docker build -t \"repo_name/image:${1}\" .; }; func"` - then run `npm run build:docker -- "1.0"`

Comment: Given that you want to pass `"1.0"` to the npm script, should the last part of your npm script example form: `... && docker build -t repo_name/image:1.0 ."` ? Presumable the `$tag` in your example is a placeholder for where `1.0` should go, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: yeah, thats right

Comment: So, have you tried what I suggested in my first comment?

Comment: yes, testing it now. seems like the param was passed correctly, however for some reasons the whole image is re-assembling. but the resulting `repo_name/image:1.0` was correct by logs - weird why is it re-building.

Comment: If you change your npm script to `"build:docker": "tsc -b && sh dist.sh && docker build -t repo_name/image:1.0 ."` _(i.e. the intended resultant compound command)_ and then run just `npm run build:docker` _(i.e. without arg `1.0` being passed)_ - does that also result in the whole image being re-assembled?
`

Comment: now not -it's already been re-built. now pushing it to hub to ensure. idk why was it re-built - repo, image, tag were unchanged. in any case maybe u want to write your comment as an answer? it seems to be a valid hack to achieve the result

Comment: For further explanation as to why the shell function (i.e. `func() { ...; }; func`) and the positional parameter `$1` is necessary refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json/51401577#51401577).

Comment: right, it does, somehow didn't find that answer during the initial search. should i delete this question or just vote to close?

Comment: there is some strange behaviour - now when i try to change tag, or even build `repo_name/image` without the tag again, the image being re-built. maybe using the bash script sets separate context for script and somehow produces this effect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228645/discussion-between-user1935987-and-robc).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can:
For example (for simplicity), for the line:

```
"build": "tsc --project "
```

You can start it like so:

```
npm run build ./src
```

This will start:

```
> tsc --project  "./src"
```

And another solution (I didn't see the point without glasses :) ), more suitable for you is to prefix the name of the parameter with `$npm_config_`, so your line should look like this:

```
"build:docker": "tsc -b && sh dist.sh && docker build -t repo_name/image:$npm_config_mytag ."
```

And then run it as:

```
npm run build:docker --mytag=1.0
```

Watch out for `=`

Comment: this will pass arguments as `string` and add them strictrly at the last position. in the sample command `tag` argument is not at the last position.

Comment: I have added the 2nd possibility, which is more suitable.

Comment: npm creates its own environment variable named  `npm_config_tag` for internal purposes. It's value is typically set to `latest`. So, just be aware that you are overriding this internal env var  with a new custom value (i.e. `1.0`) - so this has potential to produce unwanted results. If you `cd` to a project directory that contains a _package.json_, then run `npm run env` it will print many of the `npm_` prefixed variables that npm adds to the environment. You should find that `npm_config_tag=latest` already exists.

Comment: Thanks, @RobC you are right.