# Format argument value before passing to a yarn/npm script

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

I have a storybook start script which I want to run for some specific folder:

```
"storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s ./src"
```

This loads all stories from `src` folder. As the amount of stories becomes larger, I want to run stories only from some of subfolders:

```
start-storybook -p 6006 -s ./src/components/CommonComponents
start-storybook -p 6006 -s ./src/components/DashboardComponents
```

How can I format argument value dynamically in order to start storybook like this below?

```
$ yarn storybook CommonComponents
```

And it would turn into:

```
start-storybook -p 6006 -s ./src/components/CommonComponents
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass command line args to npm scripts in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json)

Comment: On _*nix_ consider utilizing a shell function. For example, define your script in _package,json_ as `"storybook": "func() { start-storybook -p 6006 -s \"./src/${1}\"; }; func"`, then run the following command: `yarn run storybook components/CommonComponents`. For a cross-plaform solution you'll need to consider writing a node.js script which is also described in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json).

Answer (score 1):

`storybook` task could be a script, and then inside the script you parse the arguments, and call `start-storybook`

1. Create a task in `package.json` (e.q `run-storybook`) and set it to execute the custom script:

```
"run-storybook": yarn ./path/to/script.js
```

```js
#!/bin/env node

// script.js

const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const args = process.argv.slice(2)
const port = args[1]
const component = args[3]

const path = `./src/components/${component}`

spawn('yarn', ['start-storybook', '-p', port, '-s', path], {
  stdio: 'inherit',
  shell: true
})
```

Then you can call: `yarn run-storybook -p 600 -s yourcomponent`

Note: make sure the script is executable: `chmod +x /path/to/script.js`.