# How to pass command-line variable in package.json script, in NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

[Pass command line args to npm scripts in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json) is almost what I'm looking for.

I use Gulp to do our NPM builds. I am able to do this, using the [yargs plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs)

```
$ gulp build --gitTag 1.0.0
```

and it produces `dist/packageName-1.0.0.zip` file. However, I need to be able to do this

```
$ npm run build --gitTag=1.0.0
```

I tried this,

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm ci && gulp build --gitTag %npm_config_gitTag%"
  }
```

...and this

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "export GIT_TAG=%npm_config_gitTag% && npm ci && gulp build"
  }
```

However, the `%npm_config_gitTag%` is not substituted with my passed-in `gitTag` argument, meaning the resulting artifact is `packageName-%npm_config_gitTag%.zip`

What should my `build` script look like in my `package.json` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the magic recipe

I simply have this in my `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm ci && gulp build"
  }
```

and use the following command line

```
$ npm run build -- --gitTag 1.0.0
```

and get the wanted `packageName-1.0.0.zip` artifact.