# how to pass args to package.json

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I want users to be able to invoke `npm run newpost <name>` from the command line, which should result in the command `hugo new blog/<name>.md` being executed. So, e.g., my package.json file might contain a line like:

```
"scripts": { "newpost": "hugo new blog/$1.md" }
```

The idea is that the $1 would be replaced by the word `<name>`. Of course, I'm just making up the $1 syntax here, but wondering how to accomplish this in the real world. I've seen posts in stackoverflow that allow you to pass parameters directly from the command line to a script that is invoked by the `scripts` entry, but I want access to the parameter directly inside the `package.json` file so I can build a new parameter to pass to the script being invoked (or, as in this case, an executable).

Please don't bother giving me a solution that complicates what the user has to type, such as setting an environment variable. My requirement is that the user only has to type `npm run newpost <name>`. However, the `scripts` entry in the `package.json` file can be as complex as needed since once set correctly, it never has to be modified again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass command line args to npm scripts in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json)

Comment: Well, first off, the 2 links above are references to the same page. On that page, there's a relatively simple solution that is bash shell only, then a much more complex solution for cross OS compatibility. Although I work in Windows 11, I always use the git bash shell, so I was hoping that the first solution would work. So, I tried adding `"newpost": "func() {hugo new blog/$3.md}; func",` to the scripts section in package.json and invoking it using `npm run newpost reactive`.

Comment: Unfortunately, 1) it failed to replace `$3` with the positional parameter and 2) insisted on adding `reactive` to the end, resulting in trying to run `func() {hugo new blog/"$3".md}; func reactive` Besides those problems, it told me "'func' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." I wonder, is this `func` thing really a bash built-in thing? Anyway, so far, no luck.

Comment: FYI, variations that I've tried: 1) using `npm run newpost -- reactive` as the command line, though according to the docs, if the parameters you want to pass don't start with '-' or '--', you don't need the '--' in your command line (I don't know how it affects positional parameter numbers, though). I've also tried including quote marks via `\"` in the command string in package.json, both around just the `$3` and also around the entire `blog/$3.md`, without success (as per the example on the page linked to above).