# How to pass arguments to piped npm scripts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have the following script in my `package.json`.

`{
  "scripts": {
    "fetcher": "node server/processes/transport.js | bunyan"
  }
}`

I try to pass command line arguments to `transport.js` script like this:

`npm run fetcher -- --days=10`

But no arguments get passed, npm dumbly passes arguments to the end of the command.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221098/passing-arguments-to-npm-script-in-package-json

Answer (score 0):

A dirty hack will be like

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "fetcher": "bunyan $(node server/processes/transport.js"
  }
}
```

then run the command

```
npm run fetcher -- --days=10)
```

Notice, with the hack, `npm run fetcher` will not work, it should be `npm run fetcher -- )`

Comment: it seems like a BIG HACK