# Pass arguments to "node" executable when running "npm run"

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to run `npm run build`, but I have to increase stack size like `--stack-size=1500`, how can I pass it to `npm`?

Normally I'd run `node --stack-size=1500 ./some-script.js --some-arg`

Let's say I can't edit `package.json`

This is not duplicate of [Sending command line arguments to npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script) because answers there describe how to pass arguments to `some-script.js` in this case, not to `node`

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no way to do it if you can't edit package.json. While editing package.json is possible, see answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221098/passing-arguments-to-npm-script-in-package-json

Answer (score 5):

I've asked a similar question about yarn. It seems that the most convenient
option is to use the [NODE_OPTIONS](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options) environment variable to pass arguments to NodeJS

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="--stack-size=1500"
npm run build
```

see also [the answer about yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46953696/pass-arguments-to-node-executable-when-running-yarn-run/48550380#48550380)

Comment: `$ NODE_OPTIONS="--stack-size=2000" node` results in `node: --stack-size= is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS` for node 10.18.1 The same for `--stack_size`.