# Pass arguments to “node” executable when running “yarn run”

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

node can be started with various options. Especially interesting is the `--inspect` flag:

```
node --inspect node_modules/.bin/jest some.spec.js
```

Is it possible to pass the `--inspect` flag somehow to `yarn run`? For example:

```
yarn run test --inspect some.spec.js
```

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317557/pass-arguments-to-node-executable-when-running-npm-run) for `npm run`, where it seems to be not possible.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In general, `yarn run ...` does not support passing arbitrary arguments to NodeJS. However, the `--inspect` flag is an exception depending on your version of Yarn.

As of March 2022, recent versions of Yarn support both `--inspect` and `--inspect-brk` arguments for the [yarn run command](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/run). The answer to your questions is now "yes", and the following will work:

```
yarn run --inspect some.spec.js
```

For older versions of Yarn (or even NPM), there are a couple of options.

First, you can use the [NODE_OPTIONS](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options) environment variable to pass arguments to NodeJS. For example,

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="--inspect"
yarn run test some.spec.js
```

then in the package.json, you can define a script to take advantage of this:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest",
  "test:inspect": "NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' yarn run test"
}
```

Second, as you mentioned, you can use NodeJS directly,

```
node --inspect ./node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js some.spec.js
```

For older versions of Yarn, those may be your only two options. However, both options work for both NPM and Yarn.

Comment: An alternative (described [here](http://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/08/24/How-to-debug-jest-tests/)) is to use `"test:inspect": "node --inspect node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand"`, which then allows running `yarn test:debug` to start a debug session in the tests.

Comment: I tried on windows with `set NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=81392"` followed by `gulp` but it doesn't seem to take effect.

Comment: `2.1.0` is the version of yarn that introduced the `--inspect-brk` support

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `npx` and pass node arguments with a `-n` or `--node-arg` flag`npx -n=--inspect-brk jest`

`npx` feels more intuitive when dealing with cli's or packages that alias commands.

Comment: this answer would fit more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317557/pass-arguments-to-node-executable-when-running-npm-run

Since there is no npx for yarn

Comment: @dre-hh there is `yarn dlx` for yarn 2+.