# Passing parameter to npm run script command

Tags: node.js

I have npm script defined like this

```
"scripts": {
    "compress": "uglifyjs src/script.js -o src/script.js"
}
```

which I can run by the command `npm run compress`.

I want to make the name of the base folder i.e. 'src' dynamic, so I can pass the base folder name as param while running the script, something like

```
npm run compress --base_folder=src
```

to run script

```
"compress": "uglifyjs ${base_folder}/script.js -o ${base_folder}/script.js"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending command line arguments to npm script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script)

Comment: I checked that question, but I want to embed a param as string to my command in scripts

Comment: See the answer under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221098/passing-arguments-to-npm-script-in-package-json

Answer (score 1):

You need [npm-config](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config). Use `$npm_config_base_folder` in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "compress": "uglifyjs $npm_config_base_folder/script.js -o $npm_config_base_folder/script.js"
}
```

Then execute `npm run compress --base_folder=src`.

Answer (score 0):

The best option will be to use environment variables because npm as far as now doesn't support such complicated logic. In other hand, environment variables offer similar functionality.

command:

```
base_folder=src npm run compress
```

package.json:

```
"compress": "uglifyjs $base_folder/script.js -o $base_folder/script.js"
```

Comment: @FarazShuja are you using Linux/macOS?

Comment: what happens if you run following command `TEST=foo && echo $TEST`?

Comment: I am using git shell on windows 10, the command output foo for me.

Comment: So seems like enviroment variables is working fine for you, maybe you really missing file `$base_folder/script.js` where $base_file is replaced with value that you're using?