# Passing environment arguments to npm commands in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, package.json

I have a script section in my package.json file as shown below

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node_modules/.bin/grunt transpile && node dist/src/app.js",
}
```

when I run "npm start" from command shell it works fine. Now I have the requirement to introduce two environment variables which my js code is accessing as below

```
if (process.env.APP_DATA_MODE === "complete") {
    // perform some actions here
} else {
    // perform some actions here
}

if (process.env.HOST_NAME === "dev") {
    // do some dev env related code here
} else {
    // do prod related code here
}
```

What I want to know is how should I introduce these two environment variables in the "start" command above OR at the very least how I can run the npm start command and also specify arguments for the two environment variables listed above

Already tried [stack overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221098/passing-arguments-to-npm-script-in-package-json) which does look like a close match but having no luck there as the environment variable keep coming as blank during code execution

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
"start": "node_modules/.bin/grunt transpile && APP_DATA_MODE=complete HOST_NAME=dev node dist/src/app.js"
```

Assuming you need pass them to your app.js

Okay so I guess I wasn't convincing enough so let me provide a simple proof
Let's write a simple script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "VAR1 = $VAR1"
echo "VAR2 = $VAR2"
```

Here's the output

[image: no env vars set]

[image: with env vars]

Comment: That returns with error with module not found saying 

my-app\APP_DATA_MODE=complete cannot be resolved

If I run it with 

node  dist/src/app.js APP_DATA_MODE=complete HOST_NAME=dev
it runs fine but it doesn't set the environment variables

Comment: Sorry 'node' call was in the wrong place. Have updated the answer

Comment: Yeah I figured. Even after putting the node call first and then adding arguments after like below

node dist/src/app.js APP_DATA_MODE=complete HOST_NAME=dev

Command runs fine but it doesn't set the environment variables

Comment: You've missed the point env vars should be at the beginning before node