# Issues passing arguments from npm command line to package.json with a bash script

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, arguments, package.json

This is a slightly different question than [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221098/passing-arguments-to-npm-script-in-package-json).

I'm looking for the best way to pass command line arguments into my package.json file and npm scripts. I'm not interested in passing it, ultimately, into a script.

There are questions about how to do this but none specifically addressing the issues with trying to use a bash function in the package.json

My npm script is:

`"Gocommit": "f() { cd dev; git add -A; git commit -m '$1'; git push;}; f"`

I want to be able to write..

`npm run Gocommit message`

or

`npm run Gocommit -- message`

And have it use my flag or argument as the commit message.

But it just keeps using `$1`

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: At a glance, since `package.json` is JSON and **NOT** a bash script, then I'd suggest you actually put your "function" into a a "script" which can actually be executed with arguments.

Comment: If I move my script to `script.sh` and make my npm script `sh script.sh`, it still just returns the $1 as my commit message.

Comment: Well you have actually surrounded it with 'quotes' here. Remove them.

Comment: @NeilLunn Just got that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes I made to fix.

1. Move bash script to bash script

Npm script is now: `sh script.sh`

2) Don't need the function wrap in the .sh script or the quotes.

Final script is: `cd dev; git add -A; git commit -m "$*"; git push;`

Comment: `cd dev || return`. Otherwise, you can still run the `add` and `commit` even if the `cd` fails.

Comment: Also, `git commit -m $1` needs to be `git commit -m "$1"` or commit messages with whitespace (you put whitespace in your commit messages, right?) will break.

Comment: (When embedding code inside a JSON string, that means `\"$1\"`).

Comment: Thanks, yeah I am concerned this will just pass in one word commit messages. Let me try your suggestion

Comment: Yeah so `npm run Gocommit message test` becomes `sh script.sh "message" "test"` So I need a way of capturing all the arguments into one variable

Comment: Better practice would be usage like `npm run Gocommit "message test"`. Gives the user more control that way -- if you don't quote, there's a significant set of expansions you don't want and can't avoid.

Comment: ...for instance, consider if you ran `npm run Gocommit ignore files matching *.txt`. Without the quotes, the `*.txt` is replaced with a list of text files in the current directory before your function is called. If, instead, you made it `npm run Gocommit "ignore files matching *.txt"`, that's mooted.

Comment: ...also, using only `$1` for the message (and requiring the user to quote) means that `$2` and onward are available for future extension.

Comment: Amazing feedback @CharlesDuffy. Thanks. Is there anyway to detect if the user has left off quotes and ignore?

Comment: Whenever the OS starts a new program, the calling convention is `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, so before a shell can actually start an external program like `npm`, the original command line was already deconstructed into a list of separate C strings, expanded globs, etc. Quoting provides instruction *to the user's shell* as to how to do that conversion, but by the time `npm` is started, it's impossible to tell whether something was entered as `hello\ world`, `"hello world"`, `'hello world'`, `hello' 'world`, etc., because they all turn into the same array element.