# Development npm run script not displaying node errors

Tags: node.js, npm

Using npm run script to start dev: `"dev": "NODE_PATH=\"$(pwd)\" nodemon -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill src/index.js",`

When an error occurs in node (my code is wrong) the following id displayed:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-45-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/karlm/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/node" "/home/karlm/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/npm" "run" "start" "--" "--config" "configs/config.json"
npm ERR! node v7.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! proj@1.1.1 start: `NODE_PATH="$(pwd)" node -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill src/index.js "--config" "configs/config.json"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the proj@1.1.1 start script 'NODE_PATH="$(pwd)" node -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill src/index.js "--config" "configs/config.json"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the avhs-frontdoor package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     NODE_PATH="$(pwd)" node -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill src/index.js "--config" "configs/config.json"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs proj
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls proj
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/karl/dev/node/proj/npm-debug.log
```

npm-debug.log gives nothing. This is quite irritating. Is there anyway for npm to pipe the actual node error out into the console?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744964/what-does-the-elifecycle-node-js-error-mean

Comment: @vp_arth That question/answer helped nothing.

Comment: offtopic: for what you need a babel in node7?

Comment: @vp_arth ES2015/ES2016 support