# Does not run command npm run build:prod Angular 2 project in production linux server

Tags: linux, angular, npm, server, production

Execute the command npm run build:prod

I do not know if the error is in the port, or in one of the files.

```
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.4/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.4/bin/npm" "run" "build:prod"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! venfi@3.3.0 build:prod: `webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the venfi@3.3.0 build:prod script 'webpack --config  config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the venfi package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs venfi
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls venfi
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/clients/client6/web5/web/venfi/npm-debug.log
```

I have tried for many days, what can I do?

Thank you,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the ELIFECYCLE Node.js error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744964/what-does-the-elifecycle-node-js-error-mean)

Comment: No, it's very different.