# NPM ELIFECYCLE error - using node server.js command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am deploying test-bot on ibm watson as described here https://github.com/eciggaar/text-bot and when I am trying to deploy code locally using CLI foundry it is getting the following errors.

I am using Nodejs version 6.10.3 and npm version 5.0.4

can someone please help me with this.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! text-bot@0.1.2 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the text-bot@0.1.2 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PRERNA CHUGH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-29T13_36_22_995Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the ELIFECYCLE Node.js error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744964/what-does-the-elifecycle-node-js-error-mean)

Comment: Are you receiving any certificate error ?

Answer (score 36):

Sometimes, when you already started your web server, the `ELIFECYCLE` error comes if you try to run the `npm` command again on another terminal (cmd). Make sure that you don't have any other instance running up in the same *port*.

Try to clean your cache with: `npm cache clean` with *Administrator/root* and delete your `node_modules`, after this steps, try to install your packages again with `npm install --save`

Answer (score 0):

Check the mappings in package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Make sure that server.js is present in the app directory.

Answer (score 0):

If clearing the cache does not work, this step may. Try and kill the process running on the specific port (let's say 3000). It worked in my situation. Type the below in your terminal and also ensure you are in the correct directory too.

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:3000 | grep LISTEN | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 2 -d ' ' | xargs kill -9
```

Best of luck !!

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it was my firewall that blocked some program access to internet.

Answer (score -4):

In case you used Windows OS the PATH Environment variable was not including the directory of "node". Check it and add it. Maybe it helps.

1. Check with echo %PATH%
2. And then add it with set PATH=%PATH;
3. Then try the installation again

Regards

Comment: This is related to npm and not related to windows path env variables