# React native build fails

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have been stuck on this for a couple of days. No idea what this error means. The last library installed was react-native-svg though it didn't cause any error the first time I ran it. Don't know what the problem is

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5bKx.jpg)

```
C:\Users\femi\Signit>npm run android-windows

> Signit@0.0.1 android-windows C:\Users\femi\Signit
> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js - 
-bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets- 
dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android

Loading dependency graph...events.js:167
     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
     ^

Error: EIO: i/o error, lstat 'C:\Users\femi\Signit\node_modules\react- 
native\ReactAndroid\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\modules\location'
Emitted 'error' event at:
  at NodeWatcher.checkedEmitError(C:\Users\femi\Signit\node_modules\sane\src\
node_watcher.js:159:10)
  at Walker.emit (events.js:182:13)
  at C:\Users\femi\Signit\node_modules\walker\lib\walker.js:52:12
  at C:\Users\femi\Signit\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
  at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Signit@0.0.1 android-windows: `react-native bundle --platform 
android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output 
android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest 
android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android`

npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Signit@0.0.1 android-windows script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\femi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03- 
06T05_58_55_991Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question and copy paste the output of your terminal instead of using a screenshot. Screenshots are not really recommended. Also, take your time for the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Consider posting your log file.  Also, consider this SO question regarding ELIFECYCLE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845335/npm-elifecycle-error?noredirect=1&lq=1