# how to fix service unavailable 503 error in DXR while building using make

Tags: mozilla, cross-reference

I am trying to build DXR for my source code. Instead of cloning DXR source code from github, I copied and using it. While building dxr using makefile I am getting error "503 service unavailable".

I am using makefile from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/dxr) to build it

Error:

```
server:/users/naek/DXR/DXR_mozilla/dxr> make

cd tooling/node && npm install

> DXR@2.0.0 preinstall /users/nsekar/DXR/DXR_mozilla/dxr/tooling/node
> lockdown


NPM Lockdown is here to check your dependencies!  Never fear!
using registry: registry.npmjs.org


> DXR@2.0.0 preinstall /users/nsekar/DXR/DXR_mozilla/dxr/tooling/node
> lockdown

npm ERR! code E503
npm ERR! 503 Service Unavailable: lockdown@0.0.6

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /users/naek/.npm/_logs/2019-01-24T12_18_51_517Z-debug.log

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! DXR@2.0.0 preinstall: `lockdown`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the DXR@2.0.0 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /users/naek/.npm/_logs/2019-01-24T12_18_51_584Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the ELIFECYCLE Node.js error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744964/what-does-the-elifecycle-node-js-error-mean)

Comment: It didnt solve my problem