# Issue with NPM run Error 126 in Vue.js web app

Tags: html, vue.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to compile a `Vue.js` app. However when I run the command `npm run prod` I run into the following issue:

```
sh: /Users/antoinevandenheste/Downloads/magicfactory-1/node_modules/.bin/webpack: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! vue-piaf@2.0.2 prod: `webpack --config src/.webpack/prod.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-piaf@2.0.2 prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/antoinevandenheste/.npm/_logs/2019-06-06T06_47_42_334Z-debug.log
```

I have no idea what the issue is but I can't seem to get past this. Any help would be much appreciated. Bellow is the code in my Package.json. I have also tried `npm install` and deleting `package-lock.json`.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vue-piaf",
  "version": "2.0.2",
  "description": "Piaf - Vue 2 Bootstrap 4 Admin Dashboard Template",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --history-api-fallback --progress --config src/.webpack/dev.js",
    "prod": "webpack --config src/.webpack/prod.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Vue",
    "Vue 2",
    "Webpack 4"
  ],
...
}
```

Comment: Are any of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744964) helpful? E.g. does the problem go away if you just reboot?

Comment: haven't tried all yet, but most are not working

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Clear out all the modules and reinstall.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```