# How can I fix this error :- Error! code ELIFECYCLE errno 130`

Tags: node.js, express, npm

When I stop running the project, the following error is displayed, but it works fine. What should I do?

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 130
npm ERR! expresssocket@1.0.0 dev: `nodemon app`
npm ERR! Exit status 130
```

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok

13 verbose stack Exit status 130
18 verbose node v12.13.0
19 verbose npm  v6.12.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 130
22 error expresssocket@1.0.0 dev: `nodemon app`
22 error Exit status 130
23 error Failed at the expresssocket@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 130, true ]
```

Comment: Can you please provide the data and code used to produce this error as per a reproducible example?

Comment: please mention the being used version of npm, node and nodemon, and alsoPlease can you try with the current debug version: npm install -g nodemon@debug (1.18.2-alpha.1)

Comment: Might be worth looking at [this question about causes of `ELIFECYCLE` errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744964/what-does-the-elifecycle-node-js-error-mean), to try to diagnose why it's happening.