# Composer hanging while updating dependencies

Tags: json, composer-php, hamcrest

I tried updating a Laravel project I'm working on today using `composer update`

But it hung on `Updating dependencies (including require-dev)`

So I tried things like updating composer, dump-autoload, but nothing seemed to work. Then I ran it in verbose mode: `composer update -vvv`

And I noticed it hung while reading this json:

```
Reading path/to/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-cordoval$hamcrest-php.json from cache
```

I tried searching for cordoval/hamcrest-php on packagist.org and couldn't find it. This isn't listed as a dependency in my `composer.json`

Searching through my vendor folder, I notice the `mockery/mockery` package I use requires `hamcrest/hamcrest-php`, but I can't find anything that makes any reference to `cordoval`.

Any idea what's wrong and how I can fix it so that I can do the update?

Here's my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "iron-io/iron_mq": "dev-master",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.2.*",
        "mockery/mockery": "dev-master",
        "xethron/migrations-generator": "dev-master",
        "mailgun/mailgun-php": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

### Update

I've tried removing some of the packages from my composer.json, including the "mockery/mockery" package. The only change it made was that Composer would hang on a different file.

After leaving Composer running like that for quite a long time, it finally exited with an error such as the following:

```
/path/to/ComposerSetup/bin/composer: line 18:  1356 Segmentation fault      php "${dir}/composer.phar" $*
```

Not sure what to do about that...

Comment: What does your composer.json look like? Did you try doing a composer self-update before?

Comment: yep, I tried the self-update. I've updated my question with the composer.json

Comment: You can run `composer diagnose` to check if you have any connectivity issues

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. `composer diagnose` gave me a few pointers to improve my composer.json, but nothing it suggested changed the problem.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was with php's `xdebug` extension. After disabling it in my `php.ini`, composer ran without any problems.

And just to note, the hang-up wasn't actually occurring while reading files from the cache. It was the step right after where composer was trying to resolve dependencies. It just never finished that step and never printed the output. That's why no matter what I did, it always appeared to be stuck reading a file from the cache.

Comment: If you don't know why it's hanging try 'composer diagnose' cmd

Comment: I switch my network from wifi to mobile, maybe it's cached at router, strange but it helped

Comment: for me it was intellij listening on the debug port that caused the issue - closing the intellij project let composer update properly.

Answer (score 100):

In my case, it was simply taking a very long time on my 8GB ram Mac. To check the progress and verify that it is going through the dependencies, run composer in verbose mode. This was an approach I missed in the question so worth re-stating here.

```
composer update -vvv
```

Comment: This was the solution for me, it just takes a while without giving any output on what it's doing. Thus thinking that it stalls might be true in that case.

Comment: The best approach , as we will know what went wrong !

Comment: Thank you. This one really make sense.

Comment: For some reason composer, unlike pip, downloads whole package lists, which can take a long time.

Answer (score 29):

**1st of all :** Check firewall and proxy connections. If everything is ok but composer is still hanging try to clear composer cache:

```
composer clear-cache
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#clear-cache

**2nd option** If these steps does not repair your composer then it's possible that the system does not have enough RAM memory available (I faced this problem and the symptomps were the same that you describe). At this point you have two options:

a) **Increase memory (Virtual Machines or Docker) :** Your container or VM needs more available memory. Follow this guide:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44533437/3518053

b) **Generate swap file (Linux) :** Try creating a swap file to provide more memory:
(Above commands are from [composer killed while updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667761/composer-killed-while-updating))

```
free -m
mkdir -p /var/_swap_
cd /var/_swap_
#Here, 1M * 2000 ~= 2GB of swap memory
dd if=/dev/zero of=swapfile bs=1M count=2000
mkswap swapfile
swapon swapfile
chmod 600 swapfile
echo "/var/_swap_/swapfile none swap sw 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
#cat /proc/meminfo
free -m
```

Comment: I always have to come back to this answer a every few weeks and the `composer clear-cache` works for me everytime.

Comment: That is fine @JaredDunham.  The other workaround is useful for the rare cases when 1st option does not work.  Actually I faced that problem one time working with an undersized VM.

Answer (score 21):

Some times it is stuck because it is trying to use HTTP instead of https so just run this

```
composer config --global repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

Comment: OMG ️ Where were you all these times? I don't know why it worked. I tried `composer require -vvv package_name` without the above command but I saw it was using `https`. But I'm shocked there was literally no difference in those two commands.

Answer (score 4):

Working for me.
First Run command for auto load, then clear cache and run update.

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
composer update
```

Answer (score 4):

For me the issue was with xDebug. I was using IDE's terminal, and the debugger was listening to incoming connections (as always). Turning the listening off (without requiring to disable the extension) solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me:

```
composer self-update
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by running command **NOT IN VS CODE TERMINAL**

Answer (score 2):

I found this in another article, I found that doing the following below worked. It seemed to be a cache/download issue into the composer packages cache.

```html
composer update -vvv
```

Then doing the following:
Add or edit your composer file to have these settings.

```html
"repositories": [
    {
         "type": "composer", 
         "url": "https://packagist.org"
    },
    { "packagist": false }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Restart your system.

I faced the same problem today. Going by advice, turned off xdebug, but did not help. Verified all files were present. Restarted my system, and it worked.

Comment: Do you mean you gracefully rebooted the entire server?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are running the minimum required php version

Compare with the specified required php version in the composer.json file

Open terminal run

`php -v`

Cross check in composer.json file see example below

`"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
}`

Answer (score 1):

check the path of [xdebug] zend_extension = "file/path" in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by editing `php.ini` file in order to set de cacert required for ssl verification:

1. Download the file http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Edit `php.ini` to set the pat:

   ```
   [openssl]
   ; The location of a Certificate Authority (CA) file on the local filesystem
   ; to use when verifying the identity of SSL/TLS peers. Most users should
   ; not specify a value for this directive as PHP will attempt to use the
   ; OS-managed cert stores in its absence. If specified, this value may still
   ; be overridden on a per-stream basis via the "cafile" SSL stream context
   ; option.
   openssl.cafile=C:\web\certs\cacert.pem
   curl.cainfo=C:\web\certs\cacert.pem
   ```
3. Try again

Comment: Sounds insecure to be downloading your certs from Swedish hackers.

Comment: This particular swedish hacker is the creator of cURL. If we can't trust him, we can't trust anything on the internet :P

Comment: @IsakBerglind TIL cURL is just stealing my credit card information to buy skins on Valorant.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I discovered using `free` that my system had 0kb of swap storage. Creating a 1GB swap file using https://linuxize.com/post/create-a-linux-swap-file/ solved the problem instantly.

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers

Answer (score 0):

**My problem solved with: Change the wifi (I use my phone) - Waiting (about 5 minutes)**
Here is the output.

```
Creating a "magento/project-community-edition" project at "/tmp/exampleproject"
Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.4.5-p1)
  - Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.4.5-p1): Loading from cache
Created project in /tmp/exampleproject
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

After waiting I saw the following output:

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 546 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin (2.4.0): Loading from cache
```

Not sure what is the reason but I also run the following commands.

To diagnose the problem you should run the following:

```
composer diagnose
```

If you get **OK** from each line (it should be a warning but not important I had to), That means there is no problem with the composer. Try to switch wifi and do not forget to wait!!!