# Laravel composer stops package download

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

So, I tried every solution there is online..

Composer clearcache and every other command..

Every command seems to work within project except commands that contains

> composer require or composer update command

that I use to install needed packages.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhvvR.png)

It just stops without any error..

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
        ]
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

}

Comment: Run again with -v for verbosity?

Comment: Tried. It always stops on "Updating dependencies (including require-dev)"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573924/composer-hanging-while-updating-dependencies

Comment: It's disabled. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Check all of the answers for potential fixes.

Comment: Pease edit you question to replace image of text by the text (read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 if you want to know why it is helpful to do that)

Answer (score 0):

What about trying:

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel ads-site`

then:

`cd ads-site`

followed by:

`composer require kalnoy/nestedset`

I was able to successfully run it in that order.