# composer require laravel/dusk error

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.4, laravel-dusk

I am trying to install Laravel/Dusk on a laravel 5.4 application.

The command that I am running is, according to the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk

`composer require laravel/dusk`

The output in terminal:

```
Using version ^1.0 for laravel/dusk
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing facebook/webdriver (1.3.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing laravel/dusk (v1.0.10)
    Downloading: 100%
Killed
```

That `Killed` is what's bothering. So, the package is being added to my `composer.json` file but no files can be found in `vendor/laravel/dusk`

I am trying to install this on my webhost and not on my local environment.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to your machine on the host running out of memory, like described on this thread: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1815

So you may have to increase the performance on your account to be able to run more composer commands from your webhost.

Comment: They give some advice on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667761/composer-killed-while-updating