# Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::create() - Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I'm using Maatwebsite Laravel Excel to export .xls documents.
In my 'localhost' it works perfectly, but when I try to do it in production, show me this error:

```
FatalThrowableError in Facade.php line 237:
Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::create()
```

I follow all the instalation instructions in: [Laravel Excel](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/2.1/getting-started/installation)

I also can't run "composer update" in production with SSH because the process is "killed"... I don't know why.

Do I really have to run the composer update? Is this why?

I'm using PHP 7.0 and Laravel 5.3, so I use the Laravel Excel version 2.1, the 3 version is only for Laravel >5.5.

Please help me!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does `composer install` run correctly?

Comment: yes, composer install was runned correctly...

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I runned but the error continues...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added `Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel` facade string in the providers array in app.php on production site?

As you are not able to run composer update due to process killed, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667761/composer-killed-while-updating) hint related to updating on a hint related to updating on the server.

1. Run composer update in a local environment (either your local
   physical machine, or a development virtual machine)
2. Upload or git push the composer.lock file
3. Run composer install on the live server

Comment: I added this to providers array :
Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class, 

And this to aliases:
 'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,

Comment: Maybe something is breaking, try to run the composer update or upload the exact same file and other things related to this package on the server.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is... When I try to run "composer update", the process is "Killed" -_-'

Comment: I do it... I've runned composer update in my local machine.
I upload the composer.lock file to server by Filezilla
But when I tried to run "composer install" - the terminal shows me "The compiled class file has been removed" :\

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

1. I runned "php artisan config:clear" and the error has changed to:

[screenshot][1]

2. I've uploaded (again) my "config/app.php" and then it told me:

"Permission denied to write in "bootstrap/cache"

3. So I "sudo chmod -R 777 /bootstrap"

Thank you.