# Why composer package not install

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I tried install package [watson/rememberable](https://packagist.org/packages/watson/rememberable) on localhost and it's installed successfully but when tried install it on shared hosting package `killed` and added package name to `composer.json` file, but not installed source code to `vendor` folder. I tried install package by clearing composer & Laravel caches but package not installed. How I can install it correctly?

Comment: What happen when you install the package, is there any error message?

Comment: Please provide more detail. Also, it's not clear what you mean with "[...] on shared hosting package `killed`".

Comment: Not any error message. Only `killed` message @catcon

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667761/composer-killed-while-updating

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer killed while updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667761/composer-killed-while-updating)

Comment: Please provide more details such as errors etc :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are in production mode. In the .env file change:

```
    APP_ENV=local
```

Then try installing again.

Answer (score 0):

To install the most recent version, run the following command:

```
composer require watson/rememberable
```

**OR**

Add to *`composer.json`* file:

```
"require": {
       "watson/rememberable": "^3.1",
    },
```

After, Run this command in the command prompt: `composer update`

Comment: I tried this solution also but not work @Udhav Sarvaiya