# Linode stops composer update

Tags: laravel-5, linode

I keep having issues with updating my composer dependencies. The moment I start, I see

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Killed
```

What's causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably running out of memory, so the OS kills the proces. You might get more information from the syslog. Try adding SWAP to your Linode or using a VPS with more memory.

See already asked question here: [Composer killed while updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667761/composer-killed-while-updating)