# Cpanel Laravel package install getting "Killed"

Tags: laravel, composer-php, cpanel

I am try to install barcode package in my cpanel laravel project.But every time it gets killed.

command:

```
[......@host public_html]$ composer require milon/barcode
```

after few moment:

```
Using version ^7.0 for milon/barcode
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/symfony/polyfill-iconv%24535e139d88ce6708c9d8bf795da669c3fe46467f4bc7dc900e2e65a8d77b56ae.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Network is unreachable
http://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Killed
```

it also happening for all the packages I want to install like:pdf or others.Updated my composer.still not working.

Comment: [The "Killed" message usually means your process consumed too much memory, so you may simply need to add more memory to your system if possible. i copy from this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20699258/13981490)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer killed while updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667761/composer-killed-while-updating)

Comment: Generally, you should avoid running `composer require` on your server. Run it on your development system which might use more memory

Comment: then what should be my command? without composer require @NicoHaase

Comment: You need `composer require` to install a new package, but you should not run it on any external server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens for a lack of memory of your server. You can install the package in your local machine then replace your server **composer.lock** file with the local's **composer.lock** file Then go to the **terminal** and run **composer update**.