# cpanel laravel package install & update getting killed

Tags: laravel, npm, package, composer-php, cpanel

I am using laravel- 7. Everytime I try to install any package in my cpanel ,the process get killed.

```
composer require milon/barcode
Using version ^8.0 for milon/barcode
./composer.json has been updated
 Loading composer repositories with package information
 Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
 Killed
```

after that I tried installing the package in my local machine then replace my server composer.lock file with the local's composer.lock file Then go to the terminal and run composer update.
It worked few days.
But now I am facing the issue again. Now I can't even update my composer also.
When I run composer update command.
The process get killed.

```
[....@host public_html]$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Killed
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer killed while updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667761/composer-killed-while-updating)

Comment: The "Killed" message usually means your process consumed too much memory,

Comment: Usually, you should change the lock file locally and only run `composer install` on your server. Have you tried that?